# Presta 8 - How to control what form fields are displaying in forms on checkout pages

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-8

On checkout steps - first step "personal-information.tpl" has a forms for login or creating account.

I need to modify fields of this form - modify form actually. There is a gender radio input that I do not want to be seen for ex. or birthday date field.

So I have created folder form in *override/classes* and put there *CustomerFormatter.php* class -to override form class (as I do not want to modify Presta core files)

I thought that:

```php
private $ask_for_birthdate = true;
private $ask_for_partner_optin = true;
private $partner_optin_is_required = true;
```

stands for form fields to be shown or not - but it seems that was wrong..
(have set `$ask_for_birthday` to false but the birthday date field is still present in form)

What am I missing? How to control what form fields are displaying in forms on checkout pages?

UPDATE
I have found that *birthday date* in forms can be turn off in PS options.
But when I make changes in override the gender fields they are still there.

When I make change in *classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php* - it behaves as it should but when in:

*override/classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php* - nothing happens....

I work on PS 8.04

Comment: You can disable Genders from the BO, by:
 - going to Shop parameters > Customers
 - selecting Genders tab
 - removing all the genders
By doing so, the genders will disappear from the form.

On this same page, but on the Customers tab, you can also enable/disable the birth date and the partner offers fields

Comment: Yeah - found it - thank you for tip. The other thing is that in override class must extend core - which I was missing - that was reason why changes made in class did nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and will share solution.

1 -override class must extend core - which I was missing - that was reason why changes made in class did nothing.

so `override/classes/form/CustomerFormatter.php`  should start with

```php
class CustomerFormatter extends CustomerFormatterCore
```

rookie mistake..

2 - as pointed by @ébewè
You can disable Genders from the BO, by:

- going to Shop parameters > Customers - selecting Genders tab - removing all the genders
  By doing so, the genders will disappear from the form.
- Shop parameters > Customers -> Customers tab, you can enable/disable the birth date and the partner offers fields